# Exact homology sequences induce exact cohomology sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Do exact homology sequences induce exact cohomology sequences? For example, If $E\rightarrow S^n$ is a fiber bundle over an $n$-dimensional sphere with fiber $F$. Then the sequence of homology groups $$H_m(E)\rightarrow H_{m-n}(F)\rightarrow H_{m-1}(F)\rightarrow H_{m-1}(E)\rightarrow H_{m-n-1}(F)$$ is exact. Does $$H_{dR}^m(E)\rightarrow H_{dR}^{m-n}(F)\rightarrow H_{dR}^{m-1}(F)\rightarrow H_{dR}^{m-1}(E)\rightarrow H_{dR}^{m-n-1}(F)$$ is exact?

Comment: Cohomology is contravariant, so all of those maps should be pointing in the other direction.

Comment: There is a Gysin sequence in cohomology, if that's what you're asking...